# cannot figure out correct condition for while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

The assignment i'm working on is meant to display the verses to **The Twelve Days of Christmas** depending on what **number you input (1-12)**.

There are two `while` loops involved. The first is to verify the number inputted is within that range. That works fine. The second while loop uses two `switch` statements. The first places the proper suffix on the end of whatever number you type in. the second switch determines what gift is associated with the day, and then it displays the verse like so:

> On the 3rd day of Christmas my true love gave to me
>
> Three French hens,
>
> Two turtle doves, and
>
> A partridge in a pear tree

Here is my what I have done so far:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

  public class TwelveDays
      {
       public static void main (String[] args)

       {
        int lastDay = 0;  // last day
        final int MAX = 12;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get the last day and use input validation

        System.out.println("How many days (1 to 12)? ");
        lastDay = scan.nextInt();


        //Begin 1st while

        while (lastDay <= 0 || lastDay > MAX)

        {
           System.out.println("How many days (1 to 12)? ");
           lastDay = scan.nextInt();
        }


        int day = 1;      //loop control variable for song verses


         //Begin 2nd while

        while ( )
           {
           System.out.print("On the " + lastDay);



           //Output the suffix for the day

           String suffix = " ";    // temporary suffix value
           //Begin 1st switch

           switch(lastDay) 
           {

                  case 1:
                      suffix = ("st");
                      System.out.print(suffix);
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      suffix = ("nd");
                      System.out.print(suffix);
                      break;
                  case 3:
                      suffix = ("rd");
                      System.out.print(suffix);
                      break;
                 default:
                      suffix =("th");
                      System.out.print(suffix);
                      break;
             }



             System.out.println(" day of Christmas my true love gave to me");





           //Begin 2nd switch


                 switch(lastDay)
              {  

               case 1:
                   System.out.println("A partridge in a pear tree.");
                  break;
               case 2:
                   System.out.println("Two turtle doves, and");
                  break;
               case 3:
                   System.out.println("Three French hens,");
                  break;              
               case 4:
                   System.out.println("Four calling birds");
                  break; 
               case 5:
                   System.out.println("Five golden rings,");
                  break;
               case 6:
                   System.out.println("Six geese a-laying,");
                 break;
               case 7:
                   System.out.println("Seven swans a-swimming,");
                 break; 
               case 8:
                   System.out.println("Eight maids a-milking,");
                 break;
               case 9:
                   System.out.println("Nine ladies dancing,");
                 break;
               case 10:
                   System.out.println("Ten lords a-leaping,");
              break;
               case 11:
                   System.out.println("Eleven pipers piping,");
                 break;
               case 12:
                   System.out.println("Twelve drummers drumming,");
                 break;
               }



  }
}
}
```

Sorry if my formatting is poor. I am new to java.  IT seems as though no matter what condition i put for the second while, it always ends up as an infinite loop, or it just outputs whichever number gift I put in twelve times.

Comment: You yourself created an infinite loop.

Comment: There is no condition in your second while loop and you don't have a break anywhere inside the loop (other than the ones for your cases). How do you expect it to end?

Comment: Please enjoy some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to help you to debug this.

Comment: it looks, you don't need second while loop. What is the purpose of second while loop?

Comment: Second while should be: `while(lastday>0)`. Then drop the value with each loop... `lastday--;`. That's why you're getting the same every time.

Comment: Besides your loop condition, another problem is that you shouldn't be using `break` in the second `switch`.  I'll just leave it at that, let you figure out why.

Comment: @markspace, someone will disagree with us here, but I happen to agree with you. A switch statement without break after each case is usually considered dirty code, but like you I find it warranted in this particualr case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your requirement, The first `switch` should be outside the while loop as it is needed only once per input.

Now, your major problem is that the second while loop will iterate infinite times since there is no condition or a break statement to it.

so what you can do is, decrement the variable `lastDay` at the end of the second while loop and break the loop when it is 0.

the following code must help:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwelveDays {
    public static void main(final String[] args)

    {
        int lastDay = 0; // last day
        final int MAX = 12;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get the last day and use input validation

        System.out.println("How many days (1 to 12)? ");
        lastDay = scan.nextInt();


        // Begin 1st while

        while (lastDay <= 0 || lastDay > MAX)

        {
            System.out.println("How many days (1 to 12)? ");
            lastDay = scan.nextInt();
        }


        int day = 1; // loop control variable for song verses

        System.out.print("On the " + lastDay);


        // Output the suffix for the day

        String suffix = " "; // temporary suffix value
        // Begin 1st switch

        switch (lastDay) {

        case 1:
            suffix = ("st");
            System.out.print(suffix);
            break;
        case 2:
            suffix = ("nd");
            System.out.print(suffix);
            break;
        case 3:
            suffix = ("rd");
            System.out.print(suffix);
            break;
        default:
            suffix = ("th");
            System.out.print(suffix);
            break;
        }


        System.out.println(" day of Christmas my true love gave to me");


        // Begin 2nd while

        while (true) {

            // Begin 2nd switch


            switch (lastDay) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("A partridge in a pear tree.");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Two turtle doves, and");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Three French hens,");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Four calling birds");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Five golden rings,");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Six geese a-laying,");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Seven swans a-swimming,");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("Eight maids a-milking,");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("Nine ladies dancing,");
                break;
            case 10:
                System.out.println("Ten lords a-leaping,");
                break;
            case 11:
                System.out.println("Eleven pipers piping,");
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println("Twelve drummers drumming,");
                break;
            }

            lastDay--;
            if (lastDay == 0) {
                break;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you to read more about loops and logic as i can see that you are new to programming.
Technically speaking, you don't need the second while loop at all, I tried to minimise the changes that are to be made in your code and gave an answer.